# Как открывать файл в уже запущенной программе?

Tags: java

Простой код, запускает текстовый файл по месту его расположения. Файл открывается программой в виндовс по умолчанию (которая выбрана для открытия файлов данного типа/расширения).
Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы второй и все последующие файл/ы открывались в уже запущенной программе (в данном примере это блокнот), а не запускался новый экземляр блокнота.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:/temp/text.txt");
        if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
            return;
        }
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (file.exists()) desktop.open(file);

        File file2 = new File("C:/temp/text2.txt");
        if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
            return;
        }
        Desktop desktop2 = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (file.exists()) desktop.open(file);
    }
}
```

Как вы поняли сейчас результатом работы программы у меня будет открыто 2 блокнота. А мне нужно один. Мне важно понять именно способ. Блокнот я просто выбрал для примера.

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите сделать невозможно.

Ближайшее что можно сделать это закрыть предыдущую копию программы.

Comment: Дело в том, что программа с которой я планирую работать очень долго запускается и повторное ее открытие и закрытие никак меня не устроит. При этом, программа поддерживает возможность открытие в ней файлов с помощью drag & drop (то есть перетаскивание файликов в окно программы). Мне нужно открывать файлы быстро, в уже запущенной программе. Или как-то получить доступ к ней, потому что в шапке программы (как и в любой другой) есть меню Файл > Открыть. Неужели Java не умеет такого делать?

Comment: В общем виде не умеет. Тут дело не в джаве. Никто не умеет. Можно попробовать имитировать drag & drop, но это будет платформозависимый код

Comment: Вот тут как это сделать на С. Попробуй сделать по аналогии. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080724-00/?p=21483